# how to validate select Option

Tags: php, select

I want to validate select option. 
like if user select Admin then this page work for admin Login,
if user select Vendor then this page work for Vendor Login 
if user select user then this page work for userLogin

Right now i am able to Login but actually not active my select option. right now my select option not working.

My code is so far.

```
<?php
$debug = false;
//$debug = true;

require_once("/portal/scripts/backend.php");
//require_once("/portal/scripts/auditeventlog.php");
require_once("/portal/scripts/log.php");
require_once('/portal/scripts/define.php');
require_once('/portal/scripts/authentication.php');

AddLog("index.php","Start",ERR_DEBUG_HIGH); 
if($debug) $debug_string = "<pre>\n";

$wrong_user_passwd = false;
$sid_file = '/portal/auth_info/manager.sid';
//$sid_file = '../manager.sid';

$exec_command = 'read-SystemConfig.xml';
//$filename = '../systemconfigdefault.xml';

$manager_sid = '';
$redirect_url = 'manager.php';

// Session will expire in $session_expire_time seconds.
$session_expire_time = 1200; // 20 * 60
$error_msg = "";

if(isset($_POST['uname']))
{
    //$conn = pg_connect("dbname=" .MGRCONFIG_DB_NAME. " user=" .MGRCONFIG_DB_USER );
    $conn = pg_connect("host=".MGRCONFIG_DB_HOST."  port=".MGRCONFIG_DB_PORT." dbname=".MGRCONFIG_DB_NAME. " user=" .MGRCONFIG_DB_USER." password=".MGRCONFIG_DB_PASSWORD);
    if (!$conn) 
    {
        AddLog("index.php","Could not connect to Database",ERR_DEBUG_HIGH); 
        $wrong_user_passwd=true;
        $error_msg ='Error communicating to backend.';
    }

    $query = "select username,password,userrole,emailaddress from users where username='".$_POST['uname']."' and password='".strtolower(md5($_POST['upass']))."'";
    AddLog("index.php",$query,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $result = pg_query($conn,$query);
    if($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
    {
        session_start();
        $rand1=rand(100000,900000);
        $rand2=rand(100000,900000);

        $user_sesion_id=$rand1.md5($_POST['uname']).time().$rand2;
        AddLog("manager_index.php","session[user_sesion_id] : ".$user_sesion_id,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);

        $_SESSION['user_sesion_id'] = $user_sesion_id;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['uname'];
        $_SESSION['user_email']=$row[3];
        $_SESSION['user_status'] = 'OK';
        $_SESSION['user_password_date'] = $user_info->passwd_date;
        $_SESSION['user_credential'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['user_credential_time'] = time();
        $_SESSION['user_credential_expiry'] = $session_expire_time;
        unset($_SESSION['kpsadminuser']);
        //Bug Fix 5087
        $_SESSION['random_number'] = rand(1000000,3000000); //range has been choosen arbitrary

        //user role permissions
    header('Location: ui/mainframeUI.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $wrong_user_passwd = true;
        $error_msg ='Incorrect username/password.';

    }
}
if(isset($_POST['uname']))
{
    $query = "select username,password from users_registration where username='".$_POST['uname']."' and password='".$_POST['upass']."'";
    AddLog("index.php",$query,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $result = pg_query($conn,$query);
    if($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
    {
        session_start();
        $rand1=rand(100000,900000);
        $rand2=rand(100000,900000);

        $user_sesion_id=$rand1.md5($_POST['uname']).time().$rand2;
        AddLog("manager_index.php","session[user_sesion_id] : ".$user_sesion_id,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);

        $_SESSION['user_sesion_id'] = $user_sesion_id;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['uname'];
        $_SESSION['user_email']=$row[3];
        $_SESSION['user_status'] = 'OK';
        $_SESSION['user_password_date'] = $user_info->passwd_date;
        $_SESSION['user_credential'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['user_credential_time'] = time();
        $_SESSION['user_credential_expiry'] = $session_expire_time;
        unset($_SESSION['kpsadminuser']);
        //Bug Fix 5087
        $_SESSION['random_number'] = rand(1000000,3000000); //range has been choosen arbitrary

        //user role permissions
        $query = "select userrole,guid from users where username='".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
        //AddLog("manager_index.php","query : ".$query,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
        $result2 = pg_query($conn,$query);
        if($row2 = pg_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $userrole = $row2[0];
            $user_guid = $row2[1];
        }

        header('Location: ui/mainframeUI2.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $wrong_user_passwd = true;
        $error_msg ='Incorrect username/password.';

    }
}
if(isset($_POST['uname']))
{

    $query = "select email,pass from vendor_registration where email='".$_POST['uname']."' and pass='".$_POST['upass']."'";
    AddLog("index.php",$query,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);
    $result = pg_query($conn,$query);
    if($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
    {
        session_start();
        $rand1=rand(100000,900000);
        $rand2=rand(100000,900000);

        $user_sesion_id=$rand1.md5($_POST['uname']).time().$rand2;
        AddLog("manager_index.php","session[user_sesion_id] : ".$user_sesion_id,ERR_DEBUG_HIGH);

        $_SESSION['user_sesion_id'] = $user_sesion_id;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['uname'];
        $_SESSION['user_email']=$row[3];
        $_SESSION['user_status'] = 'OK';
        $_SESSION['user_password_date'] = $user_info->passwd_date;
        $_SESSION['user_credential'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['user_credential_time'] = time();
        $_SESSION['user_credential_expiry'] = $session_expire_time;
        unset($_SESSION['kpsadminuser']);
        //Bug Fix 5087
        $_SESSION['random_number'] = rand(1000000,3000000); //range has been choosen arbitrary

        //user role permissions
        header('Location: ui/mainframeUI2.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $wrong_user_passwd = true;
        $error_msg ='Incorrect username/password.';

    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css-reset.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/default.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login-layout.css"/>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui/styles/css-reset.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui/styles/default.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui/styles/login-layout.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    background:url(ui/images/body_bg.png);
}
#login_frm_wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:220px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    margin-top:-110px;
    border:#036 dashed 1px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetFocus()
{
    document.getElementById('uname').focus();
}

</script>
<title>CloudSLA Manager - Login</title>
</head>
<body onload="SetFocus();">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div id="login_frm_wrapper">
  <div class="login_box">
    <div class="login_label"><img src="ui/images/sla-logo.png" /></div>
    <div class="message_info" id="info">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="height:100%; width:100%; vertical-align:middle; padding-left:5px;"><span id="login_details">Please enter your username &amp; password to login.</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <table class="login_table" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:30%;">Username</td>
        <td style="width:70%;"><input name="uname" id="uname" type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:30%;">Password</td>
        <td style="width:70%;"><input name="upass" id="upass" type="password" /></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="width:30%;">Login Type</td>
        <td style="width:70%;">

        <select name="usertype">
        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
        <option value="User">User</option>
        </select>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right; padding-right:5px;"><input type="submit"  class="login_button" name="login" value="Login" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['perror']) && strlen(trim($_SESSION['perror']))!=0)
{
    $pieces = explode(":|:", $_SESSION['perror']);
    $error_msg=$pieces[2];
    echo "document.getElementById(\"info\").className=\"message_alert\";";
    echo "document.getElementById(\"login_details\").innerHTML='".$error_msg."'";
    unset($_SESSION['perror']);
}
else if($wrong_user_passwd)
{
    echo "document.getElementById(\"info\").className=\"message_alert\";";
    echo "document.getElementById(\"login_details\").innerHTML='".$error_msg."'";
}
else
{
    $error_msg='Please enter your username &amp; password to login.';
    echo "document.getElementById(\"info\").className=\"message_info\";";
    echo "document.getElementById(\"login_details\").innerHTML='".$error_msg."'";
}
?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this Coding Something i missed in the select option here:-

```
<select name="usertype">
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
    <option value="User">User</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: please don't post all your code, this is way too much to read for such a simple question. only post the relevant parts of code that don't work like you expected.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understood your question, but what i see is this: you aren't using `usertype` anywhere in your php-code. you're storing the username into your session

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['uname'];
```

but the usertype (wich should be `$_POST['usertype']`) is never used, so this might be the reason it doesn't work.

PS: `$_POST['upass']` also isn't really used, it's just posted into some log-messages - but maybe all this "missing" code is somewhere in your `authentication.php` or one of the other required files. unfortunately you havn't posted the relevant parts of your code from that files, so it's really hard to say whats wrong here.

Comment: :) okkk i know that but i think i need some any php condition. after that if i select admin then it work for admin otherwise vendor or user

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426409/how-to-validate-select-through-javascript